# How to traverse a word document using Apache POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx4j, xwpf

I want to traverse a word document(.docx) using Apache POI. Like, if the document contains a paragraph of text, an image and then another paragraph of text, I want to parse the document and get a XWPFParagraph object, then XWPFPicture object and then XWPFParagraph object again. Is there some way to do this? It is for a custom parser I am building. I have to handle different Nodes in the word document in the same order they are appearing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: You can do this in docx4j, but why the docx4j tag if you are using POI?

Comment: @JasonPlutext I have not yet decided on using POI. I have used POI for other tasks earlier and that is why I decided to go with it. If docx4j is better than POI for this, I don't mind switching to docx4j.

Comment: See for example https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/OpenMainDocumentAndTraverse.java